# TCSH while loop not detecting empty array

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, csh, tcsh

My while loop is not able to detect that the array I am looping on is empty. Our `csh` points to `tcsh`.

If I run the following code

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env csh

ls -l `which csh`

echo $SHELL

ls -l $SHELL

set arrname=(x nx y ny z nz)

while ( ${#arrname} > 0 )
    echo ${#arrname}
    echo "Full: >$arrname<"
    echo $arrname[1]
    shift arrname
end
echo "Hello"
```

I get the following

```sh
❯ ./test.csh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Sep  2 15:09 /usr/bin/csh -> tcsh
/bin/csh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Sep  2 15:09 /bin/csh -> tcsh
6
Full: >x nx y ny z nz<
x
5
Full: >nx y ny z nz<
nx
4
Full: >y ny z nz<
y
3
Full: >ny z nz<
ny
2
Full: >z nz<
z
1
Full: >nz<
nz
0
Full: ><
arrname: Subscript out of range.
```

But adding a simple if allows me to exit elegantly

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env csh

ls -l `which csh`

echo $SHELL

ls -l $SHELL

set arrname=(x nx y ny z nz)

while ( ${#arrname} > 0 )
    echo ${#arrname}
    echo "Full: >$arrname<"
    if ($#arrname == 0) then
        break
    endif
    echo $arrname[1]
    shift arrname
end
echo "Hello"
```

Here is the output

```sh
❯ ./test.csh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Sep  2 15:09 /usr/bin/csh -> tcsh
/bin/csh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Sep  2 15:09 /bin/csh -> tcsh
6
Full: >x nx y ny z nz<
x
5
Full: >nx y ny z nz<
nx
4
Full: >y ny z nz<
y
3
Full: >ny z nz<
ny
2
Full: >z nz<
z
1
Full: >nz<
nz
0
Full: ><
Hello
```

Am I doing the while check incorrectly? or do I have something broken in my shell?

=[EDIT]===================================================

I changed the curly braces to parenthesis but it did not change the behaviour.

{x,nx,y,ny,z,nz} => (x nx y ny z nz)

The code above reflects the changes done.

Comment: An array should be in parentheses, not curly braces.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on MacOS. I don't have csh installed on my Linux servers, so I can't test there.

Comment: Do you have to write the script in tcsh? You don't have to use `tcsh` for scripting just because the login shell is `tcsh`.

Comment: In parentheses you separate values with spaces, not comma.

Comment: @Barmar Changing for parenthesis seems to create one element in the array.
Unfortunately I am running scripts on server that is own and managed by my client. They have a whole lot of tcsh script and every time they are parsing argument in a loop (like above) I have this issue. So I patch them with this fix, which is ugly.

Comment: @Barmar Same behaviour unfortunately.